# Selecting distinct rows that have the maximum value of a certain column

Tags: oracle

Looking for some help on this issue.

I have a table that is a list of driver information and I am in need of selecting the rows that have the max report_date value.  Also, a driver can be in there multiple times for each report_date so I need distinct drivers.

How can I query that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

This will get the row (or rows) for each driver which have the latest report date for each driver.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT di.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY driver ORDER BY report_date DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   driver_information di
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

If you only want a single row per driver (rather than all rows for each driver which have the latest date) then change `DENSE_RANK` to `ROW_NUMBER`.

If you only want those rows which are on the latest date then you can remove the `PARTITION BY driver` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select distinct driver
from mytable
where report_date = (select max(report_date) from mytable);
```

Comment: yep i ended up using something like this.  forgot to check back in here after I resolved it myself.